# How to trust a self signed certificate on macOS for a Vue.js development environment

Tags: vue.js, https, development-environment, tls1.2, x509

I have a local development environment for Vue.js where I'm wanting to use HTTPS.

Within my `vue.config.js` file I have:

```
module.exports = {
    devServer: {
        open: process.platform === 'darwin',
        host: '0.0.0.0',
        port: 8080,
        hotOnly: false,
        publicPath: '',
        https: true,
    },
}
```

With `https` set to `true` I get this:

[image]
However, the certificate is trusted within the "Keychain Access" application:

[image]
I'm using Chrome Version 76.0.3809.100 (Official Build) (64-bit) on macOS Mojave v10.14.

How can I make chrome trust this self signed certificate that the Vue configuration seems to be using? Firefox gives a comparable error just stating that it's a self signed certificate.

Alternatively, is there a better way to set up HTTPS for a local development environment?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting Chrome to accept self-signed localhost certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7580508/getting-chrome-to-accept-self-signed-localhost-certificate)

Comment: I've looked at some of the answers there including getting the keychain to trust the certificate (pictured in my question), and setting `chrome://flags/#allow-insecure-localhost` to enabled. None of the applicable answers have worked so far

Comment: Use `mkcert` to generate your own and turn it into a chain and trust that.